# How to perform aggregation without using aggregator in informatica developer

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have been trying to implement aggregation of two fields in an expression. I have `overallfield` and `sysid` and I have to take count of both fields.

```
Overallfield
Sysid
V_sysid=sysid
V_overallfield=overallfield
Total=iif(overallfield=1,V_overallfield+1,0)
```

Comment: So you want the count of records where overallfield=1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Overallfield
Sysid
V_overallfield = V_overallfield + overallfield
V_sysid = V_sysid + sysid
out_Total = V_overallfield + V_sysid
```

And let me know if that's what you need.
Or if you just need a count of rows:

```
v_count = v_count + 1
out_count = v_count
```